# Minimal cardinality of a filter base of a non-principal uniform ultrafilters

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, ultrafilters

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal. An ultrafilter ${\cal U}$ on $\kappa$ is said to be *uniform* if $|R|=\kappa$ for all $R\in{\cal U}$. If ${\cal U}$ is a non-principal ultrafilter on $\kappa$, denote by $b({\cal U})$ the minimal cardinality that a filter base for ${\cal U}$ can have.

If ${\cal U, V}$ are non-principal uniform ultrafilters on $\kappa$, do we necessarily have $b({\cal U}) = b({\cal V})$?

**Thanks** to Joseph van Name for making me aware of uniform ultrafilters and the fact that this question is only (potentially) interesting when restricted to these.

Comment: You should restrict your question to the uniform ultrafilters to avoid trivial counterexamples. An ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on a cardinal $\kappa$ is said to be uniform if $|R|=\kappa$ whenever $R\in\mathcal{U}$. Here is a related question that answers the case for $\omega$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883710/is-every-ultrafilter-generated-by-a-small-set

Comment: Thanks @JosephVanName for your comment! - I will restrict the question to uniform ultrafilters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your number $b(U)$ is usually called the "character" of the ultrafilter $U$.

In general, there may be uniform ultrafilters on the same set with different characters.     For example, it is consistent with $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2 $ that some ultrafilters have character $\aleph_1$, others $\aleph_2$.

Also more complicated "character spectra" are possible, according to [Sh:915](http://shelah.logic.at/papers/915) (Topology and its Applications 158 (2011) 2535-2555)

(Of course, if $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$, then all uniform ultrafilters have
character $\kappa^+$.)